# Сбой при загрузке Не удалось распознать файл

Tags: android, google-play

При загрузке apk файла в Google Play появляется ошибка:
"Сбой при загрузке
Не удалось распознать файл." [image: скриншот ошибки]

Если выполнить команду

```
 jarsigner -verify -verbose app-release.apk
```

то выходит следующее:

> jar verified.
>
> Warning:
>   This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is not validated.
>   This jar contains signatures that does not include a timestamp. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate t
>   his jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2026-02-21) or after any future revocation date.
>
> Re-run with the -verbose and -certs options for more details.

Так что-же я делаю не так?

Comment: А вы его подписали ключом своим?

Comment: да ключ использовал свой. в Android Studio -build-generate signed apk... указал имеющийся ключ.

Comment: С проблемой сертификата разобрался, другой файл apk подписанный им был успешно принят в Developer Console. Значит проблема осталась за самим файлом APK этого приложения.

Comment: сейчас я решил начать приложение с начала, постепенно добавляя функционал, что-бы разобраться из-за чего оно не принималось. так что сейчас, уже получилось подписать и разместить моё урезанное приложение, для альфа-теста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перерыв свой код и перевернув несколько мест приложение было принято консолью разработчика. Проблема была из-за использования векторной иконки приложения, хотя gradle создал png копии. Пришлось скопировать сгенерированные картинки в каталоги mipmap-***dpi.